# how to make query of the customer who made the most purchases (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

hello i have this table in my SQL server

tblPurchase= {purchaseId,idCust,total}
tblCustomer= {idCust,name}

how to make a query if i want to find the customer name (name from tblCustomer) who made the most purchases?? thank you

Comment: Do you mean the customer who purchased most (items / money)? Or the customer who purchased most often? What did you try so far (can you show some code, please)?

Comment: Could you rework your phrasing a bit? "Most customer" doesn't make sense. Do you mean the largest "purchase" for each customer, or the one customer who has purchased the most in total, or the one customer who made the single largest purchase?

Comment: Are you asking for the customer who makes the most purchases? If so, does "most" mean number of purchases or total amount spent on the purchases?

Comment: yeah i mean the most customer who make a purchase. not the total amout of the purchase, but how many the customer make a purchase.

Comment: That would be "the customer who made the most purchases."

Comment: thank you Mr. MPelletier, sorry my english is very poor, i translate it from google.. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the customer who made the most purchases (not the largest sum cost of purchases), you can try:
**Edited to include JOIN**

```
SELECT TOP 1 idCust, name, COUNT(*) AS numPurchases
FROM tblPurchase JOIN tblCustomer ON tblPurchase.idCust = tblCustomer.idCust
GROUP BY idCust, name
ORDER BY numPurchases DESC
```

If you want the largest sum of purchases:

```
SELECT TOP 1 idCust, SUM(total) AS purchaseSum
FROM tblPurchase
GROUP BY idCust
ORDER BY purchaseSum DESC
```

Comment: but i want to display the name of the customer from tblCustomer, not the idCust, how can i do that?

Comment: See edit above adding `JOIN`.  Sorry, I didn't see the tblCustomer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could begin with something like:

```
select from tblPurchase order by idCust
```

and then add refinements after that.

- pete

Answer (score 0):

Join two tables on a common key which is equal to `idCust` and count the number of purchases for each customer:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  cust.name,
  COUNT(pur.purchaseId) AS Purchase_Count

FROM tblPurchase pur

JOIN tblCustomer cust ON pur.idCust = cust.idCust

GROUP BY cust.name

ORDER BY Purchase_Count DESC;
```